# Unable to install swig and swig decoders in Redhat 7 or ubuntu

Tags: python, redhat, swig, paddle-paddle, mozilla-deepspeech

I have installed the swig and swig decoder package from the below methods:

Swig:
yum install swig

Swig Decoders:

Clone https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/DeepSpeech/

Cd into decoders/swig/ and run ./setup.sh

Problem:
When I am importing the swig decoder library in python it's showing the below errors:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb 20 2018, 09:19:12) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import swig_decoders
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/swig_decoders-1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/swig_decoders.py", line 28, in <module>
    _swig_decoders = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/swig_decoders-1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/swig_decoders.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_swig_decoders', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/swig_decoders-1.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/_swig_decoders.so)
>>>
```

Comment: Your `python` is linking to a version of the `c++` runtime different to what `swig` is using. Try one of the following: Use the python and swig versions, which follow with the distribution, compile `swig` with the compiler that you have used for `python`

Comment: @JensMunk I am not able to understand this line                                       **Use the python and swig versions, which follow with the distribution, compile swig with the compiler that you have used for python**

Comment: Did you install Python and SWIG using yum - out of the box? If not try to remove both Python and SWIG and install using yum.

Comment: was able to install it thanks @JensMunk